# how to do datatable title in center with print time..?

Tags: jquery

```
$('#basic-datatable').DataTable( {
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'excel',
                    {
                        extend: 'print',title: "demo title",
                        customize: function ( win ) {
                            $(win.document.body)
                                .css( 'font-size', '9px' );

                        $(win.document.body).find( 'table' )
                            .addClass( 'compact' )
                            .css( 'font-size', 'inherit' );
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```

[image: See here]

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it : Find your title "h1" and add the appropriate css to it :

```
  $('#basic-datatable')
     .DataTable({dom: 'Bfrtip', 
       buttons: [ 'excel', 
                  { 
                     extend: 'print',
                     title: "demo title", 
                     customize: function ( win ) {
                        $(win.document.body).find('h1').css('text-align', 'center');
                        $(win.document.body).css( 'font-size', '9px' );
                        $(win.document.body).find( 'table' )
                        .addClass( 'compact' )
                        .css( 'font-size', 'inherit' );
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but it will help others.

```
{
   extend: 'print',
   messageTop: function () {
               return '<h1 style="text-align:center;color:red;">Page title</h1>';
            },
}
```

This way we can also add other styles if required.